# the differences between Jboss Fuse and MuleSoft for System Integration

Tags: mule, esb, jbossfuse, system-integration

What are the deference between JBoss Fuse and MuleSoft ESB? which one recommended to use for System Integration?

Comment: Both are ESB implementation from two different vendors and can be used for system integration. Which product to choose depends a lot on what and how you wish your integration to look like and of-course the cost.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Fuse's all functionalities are opensource, but at the same time the integration stack is quite large to comprehend, IMHO.
MuleSoft's some of their components need to be paid for. They are a bit away from the opensource world, but their offering seems to be more comprehensible, again IMHO. May be, it is because MuleSoft does only 1 thing that is integrations.
  Few interesting articles to read on JBoss vs Mule: 
**From MuleSoft perspective**: https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/understanding-integration-needs-based-perspective-mule-vs-jboss-esb

**From RedHat perspective**:
https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/red-hat-jboss-fuse-service-works-6-compared-mule-esb-enterprise-34

Have fun !